# Add LIMIT to INNER JOIN (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this seemingly working query:

```
    USE [Development Westy]
GO

SELECT [ToReadType_60]
  FROM [dbo].['SMART Month End'] AS e

INNER JOIN [dbo].['SMART Reads$'] AS p 
ON e.ContractNumber LIKE p.[Contract Number]
GO
```

How would I limit the number of rows returned?  I cannot seem to get it to take the LIMIT command.

I am running the above but it is taking a long time as there are millions of rows, so I want to test it using just a small selection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 [ToReadType_60]
FROM [dbo].['SMART Month End'] e INNER JOIN
     [dbo].['SMART Reads$'] p 
     ON e.ContractNumber = p.[Contract Number];
```

I would also suggest using `=` instead of `like`.  And indexes on the columns used for the `join`s can help performance.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I am aware that LIKE can cause performance issues but the data types of the columns are different (I am right in thinking LIKE will ignore the data type?)

Comment: @davidjwest . . . The incompatibility of the data types simply means that indexes probably won't be used.  `=` and `like` would then have similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TOP` command and specify the amount of rows you want returned.

```
USE [Development Westy]
GO

SELECT TOP 100 [ToReadType_60]
  FROM [dbo].['SMART Month End'] AS e

INNER JOIN [dbo].['SMART Reads$'] AS p 
ON e.ContractNumber LIKE p.[Contract Number]
```